# Deleted stock browser browing history recovering and stock browser "opened tab" information

Tags: data-recovery, crashes, stock-browser

For some reasons, I cannot see my browsing history for a week (does Android stock browser automatically delete browsing histories?):

So, has my browsing histories been deleted? If so, is there any way to recover it?

Secondly, if stock browser crashed and opened tabs weren't recovered, is there any way to find out information either by trying to recover some file that contained the information (so, I guess android equivalent of Recuva) or anything else?

BTW, I use Android Ice Cream 4.0 and my stock browser does preserve tabs, except in some crashes (not all crashes close down tabs). I use LG Optimus LTE II.

Comment: any help or comment?